# How to check if a macro argument is an integer literal in C

Tags: c, macros, literals, compile-time, c23

I'm trying to do a macro like this:

```
#define STRING(i) \
struct STRING##i \
{ \
    size_t len; \
    char chars[i]; \
}
```

but the problem is this works with `constexpr` arguments like this:

```
constexpr int ten = 10;
STRING(ten) mystr;
```

I don't want that because then `STRING(ten)` and `STRING(10)` aren't compatible types and that might confuse users of this macro.

I tried the following:

```
#define STRING(i) \
struct STRING##i \
{ \
    _Static_assert( CAT(i, ul) , "must be nonzero literal"); \
    size_t len; \
    char chars[i]; \
}
```

it appends `ul` to the literal and makes it an unsigned long literal, but fails with non-literals since it makes it a different identifier. but the problem with this is if the user has another `constexpr` named `tenul` for example.

I wonder if there's a better way to make this macro fail unless an integer literal is provided.

---

#### Edit

To add to the accepted answer, I did:

```
#define STRING(i) \
struct STRING##i \
{ \
    _Static_assert((1##i##1ul || i##8ul || 1), "argument must be positive decimal integer literal"); \
    size_t len; \
    char chars[i]; \
}
```

This makes sure octals and hexadecimals aren't accepted, only decimal literals.

Comment: Detail: C does not define _integer literals_.  It does define _integer constants_.

Comment: Should `STRING(10)` and `STRING(0xA)` map to the same type?  If the answer is "Yes", life is going to be hell!  You can attempt to make a macro foolproof, but rest assured, a better fool will come along and break it.  It may not be worth the mental gymnastics.

Comment: it wouldn't, because the identifier name is different. But I only want the distinction to be between normal integer literal in decimal and identifiers. Since no one actually writes code like `STRING(0xA)`

Comment: Who writes code like `STRING(ten)`?

Comment: I think you're going to run into problems with: `STRING(10) a; STRING(10) b;` because you're redefining the structure type.  You would need two macros, one to define the type and one to use it: `DEF_STRING(10);` and `REF_STRING(10) a; REF_STRING(10) b;` for example.

Comment: that's actually fine in C23. They made that allowed.

Comment: Can you identify where that was allowed?  I've looked at §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers of N3054 and didn't see that permission granted, but I may have missed something — or I may be looking in the wrong place for the permission.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in 6.2.7

Comment: There is no reason to do everything with a compiler. Simply write a script in any scripting language that scans the source code for `STRING` invoked with an undesired form of argument. Then call the script as part of the build procedure (or even as a commit hook in the source code control system).

Comment: I don't see text in N3054 §6.2.7 that allows `STRING(10) a; STRING(10) b;` in a single scope.  Further, Clang (Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)) with option `-std=c2x` does not allow it.  YMMV!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it does say which structs are compatible and which aren't, and says structs with the same tag and same members and names of members are compatible. Tested with the newset gcc and it works.

Comment: I also tested my code with GCC 13.2.0 which is, I believe, the latest released GCC (14.0 should be released soon, but isn't yet GA), with options `gcc -O3 -g -std=c2x -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c macro11.c`.   It fails with ```error: redefinition of ‘struct STRING10’```.  There's no `[-Werror=xyz]` tag on the end — it is simply an error.

Comment: The code in `macro11.c` was: `#include <assert.h>` — `#include <stdio.h>` — `#include <string.h>` — `#define CAT(a, b) a ## b` — ```#define STRING(i) \``` –  ```struct STRING##i \``` — ```{ \``` — ```_Static_assert( CAT(i, ul) , "must be nonzero literal"); \``` — ```size_t len; \``` – ```char chars[i]; \``` — ```}``` —  `extern int function(void);` — `int function(void) { STRING(10) a = { 4, "abcd" }; STRING(10) b = { 5, "PQRST" }; int rc = strcmp(a.chars, b.chars); if (rc != 0) puts("Different"); else puts("Same"); return rc; }`.  (Long dashes are necessary line breaks.)

Comment: If that compiles for you, please let me know the compiler version and command line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler gcc14 (named GCC (trunk) in godbolt). With -std=c23

Comment: The relevant change is in [§6.7.2.3 Tags](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.3).  The old wording (C18 or before) for paragraphs 1 and 2 was: _¶1 A specific type shall have its content defined at most once. ¶2 Where two declarations that use the same tag declare the same type, they shall both use the same choice of struct, union, or enum._  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ In N3054 C23, ¶1 is omitted and ¶2 is renumbered and expanded: _Where two declarations that use the same tag declare the same type, they shall both use the same choice of struct, union, or enum. If two declarations of the same type have a member-declaration or enumerator-list, one shall not be nested within the other and both declarations shall fulfill all requirements of compatible types (6.2.7) with the additional requirement that corresponding members of structure or union types shall have the same (and not merely compatible) types._. This allows the code to work in C23.

Comment: You can track the development of this feature in the Standard C Committee's [document log](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/wg14_document_log.htm).  The first document was N2105 (Feb 2017), with revisions N2366, N2863, N3003, N3032, and [N3037](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3037.pdf) (Jul 2022) being the last revision — the material was in the draft standard after that, AFAICT.  N2366 is very informative on the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid identifiers start with alphabetic characters or underscores. Valid integer literals start with digits. If only there was a way to check if the first character of `#i` (the macro argument converted to a string) was numeric **at compile time**. But as far as I can tell using `(#i)[0]` only works at runtime.

The question is tagged [c23](/questions/tagged/c23) so here is the only method I could think of and [only works in C23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf):

In 6.6 Constant Expressions:

> Starting from a structure or union constant, the member-access . operator may be used to form a named constant or compound literal constant as described above.

This means in theory you should be able to have code along the lines of:

```
#define IS_LITERAL(i)\
_Static_assert(((constexpr union {unsigned char f, s[sizeof(#i)];}){.s = #i}).f - '0' <= 9,\
    "Not numeric literal");
```

What this does is creates a constant anonymous union containing a `char` field and a `char[]` field and uses the `.` operator to get the `char` field which will be the first character of the `char[]` field and then checks if the character is numeric.

**Edit:** The above technically invokes undefined behavior/is not required to compile as per the following rule:

> If the member-access operator . accesses a member of a union constant, the accessed member shall be the same as the member that is initialized by the union constant's initializer.

---

Alternatively if you want a compile time error for a non literal integer value and do not mind losing the ability to use hexadecimal constants you could use:

```
#define IS_LITERAL(i) _Static_assert(1##i || 1); // Or int dummy = 1##i; or similar
```

If `i` were an identifier then `i` preceded by a 1 would not be a valid identifier name but prepending 1 to an octal or decimal constant would still be a valid expression.

**Note:** `1##i##0` can also be used to block identifiers such as `l` or `ul`.

Comment: @CPlus "Valid integer literals start with digits" C does not define _integer literals_.  It does define _string_ and _compound_ literals and _integer constants_.  Perhaps you are answering with C++ terms?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was answering with the same language OP used.

Comment: @CPlus yup this actually works perfectly for me. Thanks. One suggestion is to do 1##i##1 instead because the identifier can be `ul` or `l` or another suffix.

Comment: As for the "the accessed member shall be the same as the member that is initialized by the union constant's initializer" part, you actually don't _need_ to use `constexpr` here, since the expression will be evaluated at compile-time regardless. It rather seems that `constexpr` only brought problems to this example. Plus if you get rid of it, the code is backwards compatible at least back to C11.

Comment: Oh btw... any ASCII character lower than `'0'` passed to the macro, means that the macro will fail due to integer promotion of `.f - 0` to type `int`. You'll get a negative value which is indeed `<=9`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: “Integer constant” is indeed the C standard’s term. However, “literal” is a general computer science term that is suitable. And it is a better choice than the C standard’s term, since the C standard’s integer constants are in fact integer literals, but not all integer constants are the C standard’s integer constants. E.g., an enumeration constant is an integer and a constant and so is an integer constant in the general computer science sense but is not an integer constant in the C standard sense. It was a bad choice for the C standard to use “integer constant” as it did.

Comment: @EricPostpischil When a general term and C terminology collide, better to employ C's terms for a C answer when possible.  C's _literals_ (string and compound) have a property that C constants do not: they can have there address taken.  Perhaps that is coincidence.  C and its standard library also uses terms  like _byte_, _string_, _const_, _line_, which differs in ways from the similar _general computer science term_.  We have similar issues with _mantissa/significand/significant_ and try to migrate to the best terms, even when OP uses the terms loosely.

Comment: @chux: It may be preferable to use the standard’s terms when they are well-chosen, but “integer constant” was not, and it is reasonable to use the correct “integer literal” instead. You may  choose not to do so, but you should recognize when other people do and accept that, not suggest they are errantly using a term from a different standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite intricate, since:

- A lot of things in C can be *integer constant expressions* while they are not *integer constants*. For example `1|1`.
- C has a whole lot of ways to express integer constants, including hex, octal and binary notation (C23), various suffixes like `U` or `L`. And as per C23 also decimal separators `'`.

I'm making the assumption that it is fine that something passed to the macro, which is not an integer constant, should either result in some manner of (likely confusing) compiler error or otherwise cause the macro to return zero.

Some things like `false` or `'1'` could arguably be considered integer constants, but they are not typically something we would like to pass such a check either.

I came up with a macro that catches most but not all of the various special cases. It consists of 2 expressions:

- `(void)(struct{int ident##x;}){}.ident##x`. This creates an anonymous struct inside a compound literal. It then tries to name a struct member `ident` + whatever was passed to the macro.

  Which in case of integer constants is fine to place there, since an identifier may not begin with a number but may contain letters and numbers. But in case `x` contains any pre-processor token which are not letters and numbers, then we will get a compiler error. This will weed out integer constant expressions.
- `(#x)[0] >= '0' && (#x)[0] <= '9'` Inspired by the union trick posted by @CPlus.
  This simply checks if the first letter in the pp token is a digit, which is always the case on integer constants. (Hex, octal and binary constants all start with `0`).

Forming a macro out of these two (in C23), we put the first expression at the left side of a comma operator to discard it (and cast to `void` to hush up compiler warnings):

```
#define IS_INTEGER_CONSTANT(x) ( (void)(struct{int ident##x;}){}.ident##x  ,  \
                                 (#x)[0] >= '0' && (#x)[0] <= '9' )
```

Test cases:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define IS_INTEGER_CONSTANT(x) ( (void)(struct{int ident##x;}){}.ident##x  ,  \
                                 (#x)[0] >= '0' && (#x)[0] <= '9' )
#define TEST(x) printf("%s is %san integer constant.\n", #x, IS_INTEGER_CONSTANT(x)?"":"NOT ")


int main() 
{
  TEST(0);
  TEST(123);
  TEST(0123);
  TEST(0x123);
  TEST(1UL);
  TEST(UINT32_C(1));

  TEST( false ); // it's a bool and keyword in C23, not a macro
  int i = 1; TEST(i);
  typedef int type; TEST(type);
  TEST(nullptr);
  constexpr int ten = 10; TEST(ten);

  //TEST(1'2'3); fails here, C23 integer constants
  
  /* The following are not integer constants and give various compiler errors:
  TEST(1|1);
  TEST( (char)1 );
  TEST('1');
  TEST(1.0);
  TEST(NULL);
  TEST("hello");
  */
}
```

Output:

```
0 is an integer constant.
123 is an integer constant.
0123 is an integer constant.
0x123 is an integer constant.
1UL is an integer constant.
UINT32_C(1) is an integer constant.
false is NOT an integer constant.
i is NOT an integer constant.
type is NOT an integer constant.
nullptr is NOT an integer constant.
ten is NOT an integer constant.
```

So this failed to catch the corner case of C23 `'` decimal separators but worked with all other weird corner cases I could come up with.

Comment: If you are doing a runtime check anyway, `isdigit((#x)[0])` works from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: @CPlus What makes you think the check will be carried out in run-time?

Comment: You cannot use `IS_INTEGER_CONSTANT` in a context where a compile-time constant is required.

Comment: @CPlus Yes, no, maybe? Depends on context. The macro in itself is not an integer constant expression, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if a macro argument is an integer literal in C

There is no reason to do everything with a compiler. Simply write a script in any scripting language that scans the source code for `STRING` invoked with an undesired form of argument. Then call the script as part of the build procedure (or even as a commit hook in the source code control system).

The easiest way to do this may be to use the compiler partially, for its preprocessing function, as with Clang or GCC’s `-E` switch to provide the result of preprocessing without compiling. Then this output may be scanned for `struct STRINGtext`, and the `text` can be tested for the desired form.